# IIS and FortiWeb Serves Asp.Net page as plain text

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, iis, web-application-firewall

I use Asp.net web from and IIS 8 and sometimes I saw this result instead of Html result in my browser:

[image: Show plain text instead of Html result]

I use "FortiWeb" as Web Application Firewall(WAF) and it configured to convert request `http` to `https`.
**This error sometimes occurs in random page.** 
Am I mistaken in IIS setup?

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems to me a normal Http 200 OK message. 
It states "Content Encoding gzip" also. 
Isn't it just a compressed version of the normal HTTP resonse? Which can happen if comression is enabled in your IIS configuration.

Comment: I use "FortiWeb" as Web Application Firewall(WAF) and this configured to convert request `http` to `https`.